# Is it possible to use $logProvider for logging in config block of the module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'd like to output log messages to console when debugging. Works fine in controllers but can't get it to work in a module config block, e.g.

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .run(function($state){
    // run stuff here
  });
  .config(function($logProvider){
    $log.debug('Config debug message');
  });
```

I get an error:

```
error TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
```

Is it possible to use the logProvider in the config block of a module?

Comment: `$logProvider` is not `$log` service. What do you want to do with log provider? Provider is for configuration during the config phase

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`$logProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$logProvider) accessed during the config phase is used to configure the log service, or you can inject `$provide` to change/leverage the behavior of logservice using [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator). The log service itself has not been instantiated yet in your module `MyApp`. You could instead get a logger instance from core `ng` and use it for debugging.

You could do:-

```
 .config(function(){
     var $log =  angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log')
     $log.debug('Config debug message');
  });
```

`$logProvider.$get` will give you the constructor for logservice, you could yourself create an instance of it by calling `$injector.instantiate($logProvider.$get)` but the problem is that it has a dependency on window service which has not bee instantiated yet, so ultimately your logger instantiation will fail.

Another hacky way would be force angular to instantate logger by adding a decorator in the config block which you can set up as the first config block before any config logging is required, after that you can execute the `ctor` from `$logProvider` `getter` and get the instance of a logger.

```
.config(function($provide){
   //Just a dummy decorator
   $provide.decorator('$log', function($delegate){
      return $delegate;
  });

}).config(function($logProvider){
   //get logger instance
   var log = $logProvider.$get();
   log.debug("Got it");
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Rb8uB?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks @PSL - this works well for what I need. Just need to be able to set up some debug messages for my config blocks.

Comment: @onblur You are welcome. I have added one more way. I am not sure if there is any other better way to do this.. :(

Comment: In the first code snippet, why was the semi-colon left out after .get('$log') ?